# C# password TextBox in a ASP.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, passwords

I'm trying to create a ASP .NET website that masks the password in a registration page as the user types. I found sites that use windows form but it doesn't work for a ASP .NET website.

So if the user types in a password its masked like this

```
 *******
```

Any website or suggestion on how I can get it to work would be great.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

To do it the ASP.NET way:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBox1" TextMode="Password" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 20):

//in aspx page

```
<asp:TextBox ID="password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
```

//in MVC cshtml

```
@Html.Password("password", "", new { id = "password", Textmode = "Password" })
```

Comment: Glad that you covered ASP .NET MVC as well. +1.

Answer (score 5):

Use the password input type.

```
<input type="password" name="password" />
```

Here is a simple demo http://jsfiddle.net/cPaEN/

Answer (score 3):

@JohnHartsock: You can also write type="password". It's acceptable in aspx.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBox" type="password" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: This is great but I always have this OCD... where the property casename has to be how it's in ASP.NET format... :P +1 by the way!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txbPass" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply select texbox property 'TextMode' and select password...

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" TextMode="Password" runat="server" />
```